# Need Guidance on Handling a Paused Token pair in Uniswap : extract ETH from pair

Tags: ether, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, liquidity-provider

I currently have a token pair (Token A and ETH) listed on Uniswap DEX. However, Token A's smart contract has been paused by its issuer, rendering this token immovable at the moment. Now, I'm aiming to remove the paused Token A and separate the paired ETH.

Since these two tokens were listed as a pair, a liquidity pool maintaining their relative value has been created. Despite the pause on Token A, I find it challenging to separate the ETH using the liquidity removal feature provided by Uniswap.

In this situation, I believe I may need to lift the paused status of Token A, but I would appreciate any guidance on specific methods or alternative solutions.

Furthermore, I'd like advice on what to look out for when examining smart contracts to prevent similar issues in the future, and considerations when investing or trading tokens that include specific features like the pause function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://cryptorachel.com/ might help you. It's a legit site, you may check in the Uniswap Discord, Rachel is an admin there. Re the second question: there are many automated tools that scan the token contract for such shenanigans, like tokensniffer.